# Problem with installing champions of regnum on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, games

I was trying to install Champions of Regnum, I downloaded the linux installer 64bit, changed the permissions and executed it. But after it was done installing, I got it in the softwares and on the desktop, but neither of which would open when double clicked.

So I tried reusing the installer through the terminal and after it was finished I got the following error message.

```
/usr/local/regnum/rolauncher: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can't run it on Ubuntu 20 too. Downloaded and installed ROInstall_64. Installation finished. In the login screen I cannot even see what I'm typing. After blindly entering correct username/password the application just stops. No error message, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Manually downloading libpng12-0 from [this site](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download) and installing it worked for me.

I also had a problem with `libjpeg`, which was solved installing `sudo apt install libjpeg62`. And then I had to run the launcher using `sudo /usr/local/...` to avoid a warning.